# How can I tell PHPStorm to refactor namespaces and class names?

Tags: phpstorm

I've noticed when I move a file in PHPStorm, it doesn't adjust the namespace at all. My project uses PSR-0, so directory structure mirrors the namespacing. Is it possible to have PHPStorm adjust the namespace when a file is moved?

Also, when renaming a file the class name is not changed and I then have to go in and rename the class. Is it possible to rename a file and the class in a single step?

I'm using 7.1.3

Comment: Use **Move...** and **Rename...** refactorings applied to the actual class.

Comment: @LazyOne I thought that would do it, but when I go to Refactor -> Rename it doesn't rename the class.  Same with move and namespaces.

Comment: So ... what it does instead? Screencast please.

Comment: **Renaming class** allows to rename file as well. **Moving class** allows to change namespace as well as new folder where it will be located.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because my application is a Laravel app the root directory was not the source of the namespacing.  PHPStorm has a new option as of 8.0 that allows you to specify a directory as the namespace root: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22585

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work for me, what did you set as document root?

Answer (score 31):

I encountered the same issue. The reason was that I was trying to move the **file** (from project view), instead of moving the **class** (right click on the name in the source code).

Comment: got it. 3x. then is it possible to change namespace for multiple files in batch?

Comment: It would require a way to select multiple classes (not files) at once. I'm not a long-time PHPStorm user, I don't know if this exists. The only way I know to select a class is from inside the editor, so one class at a time.

Comment: This was the most helpful answer despite being the least voted one, thank you.

Comment: It's possible to move multiple files in batch if they reside in the same namespace and you move to another namespace - by using Move namespace refactoring (F6 on the namespace name)

Comment: Is it possible to move multiple files that are not namespaced into the same namespace?

Comment: Isn't there a way to fix the namespace automatically after the fact? I mean it has the PSR-4 config already

Answer (score 11):

If you use the `F6` refactoring, it will allow you to move the class and change the namespace at the same time: [PHPStorm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/move-refactorings.html#d841138e223)

However, you do need to have the [directory namespace mappings](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-php-namespaces-in-a-project.html) setup:

Comment: Exactly that's the way. Right-click on the classname in your file then click on Refactor -> Move, change the namespace and got for it.

Comment: F6 in the Project pane worked for me as well (PhpStorm 2017.1.4).

Answer (score 0):

To have the namespace automatically changed when moving a file, I've found that you simply need to configure your project in `Settings > Directories` and set the source root

[image: Settings dialog]

With the correct PSR-4 prefix if necessary

[image: Edit propertis]
[image: Prefix dialog]

After that any move operation will result in the namespace being automatically changed